# Pushforwards of higher-rank vector bundles on flags

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flag-varieties, schubert-calculus

Let $V \cong \mathbb{C}^3$ and let $\pi: Fl(V) \to \mathbb{P}(V)$ be the projection from the flag variety to the projective space (of lines) of $V$. Let $L \subset H \subset \mathbb{C}^3$ be the tautological flag of subbundles on $Fl(V)$.

How can I compute $$R^i\pi_*(\mathbb{S}_\lambda(H) \otimes (\mathbb{C}^3/H)^{\otimes a})?$$
Here $\mathbb{S}_\lambda$ is a Schur functor, and $i=0,1$ since $\pi$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle.

If $\lambda = (d,d)$, relative Borel-Weil-Bott (and writing $\det(H) = L \otimes H/L$) says the result is $L^{\otimes d} \otimes \mathbb{S}_\mu(\mathbb{C}^3/L)$ for some $\mu$ (as either $R^0$ or $R^1$, depending on the numbers).

Is there a form of relative Borel-Weil-Bott to handle the general case? Are the pushforwards still nice -- say, sums and/or tensor products of Schur functors of $L$ and $\mathbb{C}^3/L$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$?

(I realise Borel-Weil-Bott is overpowered for this example, but the question arose while I was trying to compute cohomology of certain more complicated tensor products on $Fl(V)$ involving the various tautological vector bundles. So I am eventually interested in $V = \mathbb{C}^n, n \geq 3$.)

Comment: Filtration $0 \to L \to H \to H/L \to 0$ gives a filtration on $S_\lambda(H)$ with factors being irreducible equivariant bundles. Applying Borel--Bott--Weil to these and using the spectral sequence of a filtered complex, you can figure out the answer.

Comment: @Sasha I think this approach shows that the pushforwards are locally free, but I don't see how it answers the question (unless there is some way to understand the differentials of these particular spectral sequences). Are you saying that the pushforward cannot be characterized beyond "has a filtration by Schur functors of tautological bundles"? For example, take $\lambda = (1,0)$ and $a=1$, i.e. twisting and pushing down the short exact sequence you've proposed (there is no $R^1$). Is the resulting extension split or nonsplit? If nonsplit, which extension is it?

Comment: (Oops, in the example there, there is only one nonsplit extension. But if $a>1$ there are many.)

Comment: In this example subobject $L \otimes V/H$ after pushforward becomes $L \otimes V/L$, and the quotient object $H/L \otimes V/H$ becomes $\Lambda^2(V/L)$. Most probably, the corresponding extension is $\Lambda^2V$. If you want to check it accurately, you may construct a morphism from $\Lambda^2V \otimes O$ to your sheaf on the flag variety and check that the pushforwards of the kernel and the cokernel are zero.